# Retrieve User name with Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to retrieve a list of User names from Event Viewer log data. The only selector that I saw available was UserID. I would like to convert that to what I see under General > User instead of a SID. I am a PowerShell beginner so I apologize in advance.

This is the script I am using right now. It works great but I would like to add a User name to the columns.

```
#Server list
$VDI = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\IM\AvayaList.csv"
 
#Query remote machines
Invoke-Command $VDI {
 
    $Filter = @{
           Logname = 'Citrix-VDA-CQI/Admin'
           Level = 1,2,3
           StartTime = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1)
    }
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $Filter
 
} | Select-Object MachineName,TimeCreated,Level,ID,Message | Out-GridView -Title "Results"
```

I saw this on another post but I am having a hard time integrating what I have with what I found.

```
  Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1000 | foreach {
    $sid = $_.userid;
    if($sid -eq $null) { return; }
    $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid);
    $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]);
    Write-Host $objUser.Value;
}
```

I am using PowerShell v5.1.14393.3866

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write a little helper function to resolve the SIDs. Also, just as you used a variable for your filter hashtable, you can use a variable to store the desired properties to make the code easier to read.

```
Function Resolve-SID ($sid)
{
    if($sid)
    {
        $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid)
        $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value
    }
    else
    {
        'N/A'
    }
}

$selectprops = "MachineName",
               "TimeCreated",
               "Level",
               "ID",
               "Message",
               @{n="User";e={Resolve-SID $_.UserID}}

#Server list
$VDI = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\IM\AvayaList.csv"

#Query remote machines
Invoke-Command $VDI {

    $Filter = @{
           Logname = 'Citrix-VDA-CQI/Admin'
           Level = 1,2,3
           StartTime = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1)
    }
    Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $Filter

} | Select-Object $selectprops | Out-GridView -Title "Results"
```

Comment: WOW. This is very elegant! This is a different approach than what my beginner mind envisioned but it works really well! Thank you Doug.